# laravel: how to stay login until a condition becomes false?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

I have a field (`can_login`) in my users table.

normally,users can login. and logout with this code:

```
 Auth::logout();
```

I want, when each time a logged-in user refresh a page,
laravel check `can_login` in user table.
if `can_login` is false, then auto logout.

I try this in `RouteServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
   parent::boot();
   if(auth()->user()->can_login){
       return route('logout');
   }
}
```

but `auth()->user()` is always empty.

Comment: IMHO I would use a `middleware` and FIY `logout` route is a **POST** route you cannot redirect to it because a redirect is a **GET** request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a middleware or add a check to your existing authentication middleware. 
On each request it passes through a middleware to check if user is authenticated and after that `auth()->user()` will not be empty.

Simplest solution would be to create a middleware in app/Http/Middlewares/CheckUserCanLoginMiddleware.php

```php
class CheckUserCanLoginMiddleware
{    
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    ) {
        if ($request->user()->can_login ?? false) {
            Auth::logout();
            return $this->sendUnauthorizedResponse();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And then register it as a routeMiddleware` in your bootstrap/app.php file.

The last thing you need is to use it to our routes middlewares after authentication middleware.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't understand 'register it as a routeMiddleware`',can please explain it more?

Comment: @aliali Yes. You can check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes there are useful examples there.